# Response status code for bulk-creating objects

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I'm creating an endpoint that looks something like

```
POST '../v1/container/{container-id}/items/bulk-create'
```

This endpoint should get a list of items data and create them under that container.
It's done syncly, i.e all items should be created before the user gets the response (as opposed to async job), and all items should be created or failed (no part creation).
I wonder what should be the response of success - should it be 200 or 201?

Answer (score 0):

Today, the [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) reference for HTTP POST is [RFC-ietf-httpbis-semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.3)

> If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a POST request, the origin server SHOULD send a 201 (Created) response containing a Location header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created (Section 10.2.2) and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s).